# sub-second latency causing delay in spark application

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I have a spark batch job that runs every minute and processes ~200k records per batch. The usual processing delay of the app is ~30 seconds. In the app, for each request, we make a write request to DynamoDB. At times, the server-side DDB write latency is ~5 ms instead of 3.5 ms (~30% increase w.r.t to usual latency 3.5ms). This is causing the overall delay of the app to bump by 6 times (~3 minutes).

How does sub-second latency of DDB call impact the overall latency of the app by 6 times?

PS: I have verified the root cause through overlapping the cloud-watch graphs of DDB put latency and the spark app processing delay.

Thanks,
Vinod.

Answer (score 0):

Just a ballpark estimate:

If the average is 3.5 ms latency and about half of your 200k records are processed in 5ms instead of 3.5ms, this would leave us with:

```
200.000 * 0.5 * (5 - 3.5) = 150.000 (ms)
```

of total delay, which is 150 seconds or 2.5 minutes. I don't know how well the process is parallelized, but this seems to be within the expected delay.